# taking time to read the records and save in the other table using java streams and spring boot JPA

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, spring-data-jpa

From the below code, i want to save the details from PersonInfoEntity table and for each personInfo, I want to store the records in ResearchInfoEntity.
I have around 100,000 records to insert from PersonInfoEntity to ResearchInfoEntity. Issue is with the below code, it is talking lot of time to save the records in the ResearchInfo table. In almost 3 hours it just stored around 2000 records. Please let me know where it is taking time to execute or if any code optimzation is required to insert bulk records.

Sample code :

```
List<PersonInfoEntity> PersonInfoEntityList = personInfoRepository.findAll();
Map<Long, List<PersonInfoEntity>> personInfoEntityMap = PersonInfoEntityList.stream().
        collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                personInfoResponse ->  personInfoResponse.getPerson().getPersonId()
        ));

List<ResearchEntity> researchEntityList = researchRepository.findAll();

 List<ResearchInfoEntity> researchInfoEntityList = new ArrayList<>();

for(ResearchEntity researchEntity : researchEntityList){
    List<PersonInfoEntity> personInfoResponseList1 = personInfoEntityMap.get(researchEntity.getPerson().getPersonId());
    if(Objects.nonNull(personInfoResponseList1)) {
        for (PersonInfoEntity PersonInfoEntity : personInfoResponseList1) {
            ResearchInfoEntity researchInfoEntity = new ResearchInfoEntity();
            researchInfoEntity.setRecovery(ResearchEntity);
            researchInfoEntity.setMilestoneGroupId(PersonInfoEntity.getMilestoneGroupId());
            researchInfoEntity.setMilestoneId(PersonInfoEntity.getMilestoneId());
            researchInfoEntity.setMilestoneStepId(PersonInfoEntity.getMilestoneStepId());
            researchInfoEntity.setMilestoneStepValue(PersonInfoEntity.getMilestoneStepValue());
            researchInfoEntity.setCreateBy(PersonInfoEntity.getCreateBy());
            researchInfoEntity.setCreateTime(PersonInfoEntity.getCreateTime());
            researchInfoEntity.setUpdateBy(PersonInfoEntity.getUpdateBy());
            researchInfoEntity.setUpdateTime(PersonInfoEntity.getUpdateTime());
             researchInfoEntityList.add(researchInfoEntity);
           // researchInfoEntityRepository.save(recoveryMilestoneStep);
        }
        researchInfoEntityRepository.saveAll(researchInfoEntityList);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mapping of `PersonInfoEntity` to `researchInfoEntity` could be done [asynchronously](https://www.baeldung.com/java-asynchronous-programming).

You could also try to use `parallelStream`:

```java
public void yourMethod() {
    List<PersonInfoEntity> PersonInfoEntityList = personInfoRepository.findAll();
    Map<Long, List<PersonInfoEntity>> personInfoEntityMap = PersonInfoEntityList.stream().
            collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    personInfoResponse -> personInfoResponse.getPerson().getPersonId()
            ));

    List<ResearchEntity> researchEntityList = researchRepository.findAll();

    List<ResearchInfoEntity> researchInfoEntityList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (ResearchEntity researchEntity : researchEntityList) {
        List<PersonInfoEntity> personInfoResponseList1 = personInfoEntityMap.get(researchEntity.getPerson().getPersonId());
        if (Objects.nonNull(personInfoResponseList1)) {
            List<ResearchInfoEntity> researchInfoListFromPerson = personInfoResponseList1
                    .parallelStream() // <--
                    .map(this::toResearchInfoEntity)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            researchInfoEntityList.addAll(researchInfoListFromPerson);
        }
    }
    researchInfoEntityRepository.saveAll(researchInfoEntityList);
}

private ResearchInfoEntity toResearchInfoEntity(PersonInfoEntity personInfoEntity) {
    ResearchInfoEntity researchInfoEntity = new ResearchInfoEntity();
    researchInfoEntity.setRecovery(ResearchEntity);
    researchInfoEntity.setMilestoneGroupId(PersonInfoEntity.getMilestoneGroupId());
    researchInfoEntity.setMilestoneId(PersonInfoEntity.getMilestoneId());
    researchInfoEntity.setMilestoneStepId(PersonInfoEntity.getMilestoneStepId());
    researchInfoEntity.setMilestoneStepValue(PersonInfoEntity.getMilestoneStepValue());
    researchInfoEntity.setCreateBy(PersonInfoEntity.getCreateBy());
    researchInfoEntity.setCreateTime(PersonInfoEntity.getCreateTime());
    researchInfoEntity.setUpdateBy(PersonInfoEntity.getUpdateBy());
    researchInfoEntity.setUpdateTime(PersonInfoEntity.getUpdateTime());
    return researchInfoEntity;
}
```

Also, trying to work with 100 000 elements at once takes up a lot of memory. You could try processing your elements in batches.

For example:

```java
public void export(int batchSize) {
    int numberOfElementFetched;
    int pageCount = 0;
    do {
        // entityManager.clear(); // Needed only if you are in a transactional state, you need to clear the entity manager.
        // Otherwise, for every iteration, it will keep previous fetched elements in memory
        PageRequest requestByBatch = PageRequest.of(pageCount, batchSize, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC));
        numberOfElementFetched = yourMethod(requestByBatch);
        pageCount++;
    }
    while (numberOfElementFetched == batchSize);
}

public void yourMethod(PageRequest pageRequest) {
    List<PersonInfoEntity> PersonInfoEntityList = personInfoRepository.findAll();
    Map<Long, List<PersonInfoEntity>> personInfoEntityMap = PersonInfoEntityList.stream().
            collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    personInfoResponse -> personInfoResponse.getPerson().getPersonId()
            ));

    List<ResearchEntity> researchEntityList = researchRepository.findAll(pageRequest).getContent();

    List<ResearchInfoEntity> researchInfoEntityList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (ResearchEntity researchEntity : researchEntityList) {
        List<PersonInfoEntity> personInfoResponseList1 = personInfoEntityMap.get(researchEntity.getPerson().getPersonId());
        if (Objects.nonNull(personInfoResponseList1)) {
            for (PersonInfoEntity PersonInfoEntity : personInfoResponseList1) {
                ResearchInfoEntity researchInfoEntity = new ResearchInfoEntity();
                researchInfoEntity.setRecovery(ResearchEntity);
                researchInfoEntity.setMilestoneGroupId(PersonInfoEntity.getMilestoneGroupId());
                researchInfoEntity.setMilestoneId(PersonInfoEntity.getMilestoneId());
                researchInfoEntity.setMilestoneStepId(PersonInfoEntity.getMilestoneStepId());
                researchInfoEntity.setMilestoneStepValue(PersonInfoEntity.getMilestoneStepValue());
                researchInfoEntity.setCreateBy(PersonInfoEntity.getCreateBy());
                researchInfoEntity.setCreateTime(PersonInfoEntity.getCreateTime());
                researchInfoEntity.setUpdateBy(PersonInfoEntity.getUpdateBy());
                researchInfoEntity.setUpdateTime(PersonInfoEntity.getUpdateTime());
                researchInfoEntityList.add(researchInfoEntity);
            }
        }
    }
    researchInfoEntityRepository.saveAll(researchInfoEntityList);
    return researchEntityList.getSize();
}
```

Comment: I was trying the first method you suggested. IN toResearchInfoEntity(..) researchInfoEntity.setRecovery(ResearchEntity); how to set ResearchEntity as we have not passed the ResearchEntity to the toResearchInfoEntity(..) method.

Comment: You can add more parameters to `toResearchInfoEntity` method. 

`toResearchInfoEntity(PersonInfoEntity personInfoEntity, ResearchEntity researchEntity)`